# update stripe plan with incorrect amount due

Tags: php, symfony, payment, stripe-payments

I m using stripe for my payment. Everything works fine exept one thing.

I have 4 different plans : Free(0€) / free + extra (4,90€) / premium (49€) / premium + extra (53,90€).

The user can update the subsciption, like that :

```
// i get the $plan variable by my ajax request
$newPlan = $plan;

// i find the name of the current user's plan in my database
$payment = $em->getRepository('CacPaymentBundle:Payment')->findOneByUser($id);
$customerId = $payment->getCustomerId();

// i update my user's stripe plan
$cu = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($customerId);
$planId = $cu->subscriptions->data[0]->id;
$subscription = $cu->subscriptions->retrieve($planId);
$subscription->plan = $newPlan;

// i update my plan in my database
$subscription->save();
$payment->setPlan($newPlan);
$em->persist($payment);
$em->flush();
```

Here is my probleme : In my stripe back office, the user has the right plan but the amount due is not correct.

When i update to free + extra to premium with extra, the amount due is 102€ and few cents

I don't understand why my amount is not correct and my plan is correct

Any idea is welcome :)

Thanks

Comment: You'd need to provide way more details, especially a screenshot of the prorated amounts or the exact amounts you charged in the previous invoice and the one you got after updating. You can also find more details about proration here: https://stripe.com/docs/guides/subscriptions#upgrading-or-downgrading-plans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stripe calculates a percentage of the subscription with respect to time.

That's why the amount I get was not the one to which I wanted